# Zeta-like function with offset

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

Is there a known function of the form:

$$\zeta(s,a) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s+a},$$

and if so what is its name?

Comment: I don't know if your function has a name, but it is similar to the Hurwitz zeta function $\displaystyle \zeta(s,a) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^s}$.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton I am not able to discern the claimed resemblance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $a$ is small, i.e. $0<a<1$. Then
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s + a} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} \frac{1}{1 + a n^{-s}} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-a)^{m-1} \zeta(m s)
$$
If $a$ is larger in absolute value, we may need to keep $p$ initial terms, so as to make sure that $|a| < (p+1)^{s}$:
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s + a} = \sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n^s + a} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-a)^{m-1} \zeta(m s, p+1)
$$
where $\zeta(s,a)$ stands for the [Hurwitz zeta-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).